# pandas group by date in pandas 2.0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have this dataframe

```
date         in_count  out_count
2013-01-03,  1.00000,   0.00000
2013-03-04,  1.00000,   0.00000
2013-04-08,  1.00000,   0.00000
2013-04-22,  1.00000,   0.00000
2013-05-06,  0.00000,   1.00000
```

the idea is to grouping by weeks. in the past the software use pandas=0.24.2, but i need to change to pandas 2.0, so for pandas 0.24.2 i have this

```
by_week_df = articles_df.set_index(
    pd.DatetimeIndex(articles_df['date'])
    ).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1W')).sum().reset_index()
```

but running on pandas 2.0 i have the next error:

```
  File "pandas/_libs/groupby.pyx", line 717, in pandas._libs.groupby.group_sum
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.date'
```

i tried to convert first the date column to datetime but i obtain the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're duplicating the `date` column into the index. What's new in Pandas 2 is that it doesn't ignore non-numeric columns when doing a groupby sum, hence the error. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html):

> `numeric_only` `bool`, default `False`
>
> Include only float, int, boolean columns.

Whereas [previously](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

> `numeric_only` `bool`, default `True`

One solution is to convert to datetime first then set the column as the index, for example:

```
articles_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(articles_df['date'])
by_week_df = articles_df.set_index('date').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1W')).sum()
```

Result:

```
            in_count  out_count
date                           
2013-01-06       1.0        0.0
2013-01-13       0.0        0.0
2013-01-20       0.0        0.0
...              ...        ...
2013-04-28       1.0        0.0
2013-05-05       0.0        0.0
2013-05-12       0.0        1.0

[19 rows x 2 columns]
```

Or simply change your existing code to use `.sum(numeric_only=True)`, but I think my solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws a `ValueError: cannot insert date, already exists` in [`2.0.1`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v2.0.1.html).

Try this :

```
by_week_df = (articles_df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(articles_df.pop('date')))
                  .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1W')).sum().reset_index())
```

Output :

```
print(by_week_df)

         date     in_count    out_count
0  2013-01-06         1.00         0.00
1  2013-01-13         0.00         0.00
2  2013-01-20         0.00         0.00
..        ...          ...          ...
16 2013-04-28         1.00         0.00
17 2013-05-05         0.00         0.00
18 2013-05-12         0.00         1.00

[19 rows x 3 columns]
```